# Changing Button Text on Text Input - JS, RoR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a `Price Range` button that when clicked will open a popover. In that popover, there are two input boxes. A `Min Rent` box and a `Max Rent` box. Once values are entered in that box I would like the `Price Range` box to now display the values that were previously entered. Something like `$2000 to $2500`. I have looked and looked on Google and other StackOverflow questions and answers, but I am not sure how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Erb File:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
  <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-price-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">Price Range <span class="caret"></span></a>
</div>

<div id="listing-price-content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <%= f.text_field :min_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Min Rent", data: { "binding-name" => "min-price" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <%= f.text_field :max_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Max Rent", data: { "binding-name" => "max-price" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS File:

```
$('#listing-price-selector').popover( {
  html: true,
  trigger: 'manual',
  placement: 'bottom',
  template:  '<div class="popover price-range-pop" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
  content: function() {
    return $('#listing-price-content').html();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to trigger a function from a change event (keyup) on either of the inputs inside the popover.

The tricky thing here, at least to me, is that the content of the popover is dynamically generated, so trying to assign an event handler for those elements at page load won't work.

What does work is to assign the event handler once those elements have been generated.

There are events that are fired for the popover itself that you can assign a handler on, and that will get you where you need.

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
  $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#min-price").keyup(modPrice);
  $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#max-price").keyup(modPrice);
});
```

and then modPrice can be a function to fix the value of the price range box.  Something like:

```
function modPrice(){
  var mn = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#min-price").val();
  var mx = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#max-price").val();
  mn = (mn == "") ? 0 : mn;
  mx = (mx == "") ? 0 : mx;
  $("#listing-price-selector").text(mn + " to " + mx);
}
```

In there you can do a lot more processing, such as making sure max is over min, or whatever you like.

Hope this helps!

PS - got the popover events from W3Schools ref page: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp

PPS - and for fun, I made a snippet example, here it is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
  <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-price-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">Price Range <span class="caret"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
  <input type="text" id="priceBox" />
</div>


<div id="listing-price-content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <label>Min</label>
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <input type="text" id="min-price" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <label>Max</label>
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <input type="text" id="max-price" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

$('#listing-price-selector').popover( {
  html: true,
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom',
  template:  '<div class="popover price-range-pop" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
  content: function() {
    return $('#listing-price-content').html();
}
  
});

$("[data-toggle='popover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
  $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#min-price").keyup(modPrice);
  $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#max-price").keyup(modPrice);
});

$("[data-toggle='popover']").on('hide.bs.popover', function(){
  modPrice();
});

function modPrice(){
  var mn = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#min-price").val();
  var mx = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#max-price").val();
  mn = (mn == "") ? 0 : mn;
  mx = (mx == "") ? 0 : mx;
  $("#priceBox").val(mn + " to " + mx);
  $("#listing-price-selector").text(mn + " to " + mx);
}

</script>
```